# Optimizing non-convex functions on convex sets

Tags: optimization, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

I'm interested in the optimization problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & x^T M \, x\\ \text{subject to} & \| x \| \leq 1\\ & x \geq 0\end{array}$$

where $M$ is positive definite. As I understand it, this isn't a convex problem, but the constraints should define a convex set. Is there a well-known way of solving this sort of problem?

For those curious about how I might have gotten here: I have $c$ sensors, each of which has $k$ features. I want to find a convex combination of the $k$ features per sensor that maximizes the distance between some patterns over the sensors.

Comment: This seems relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145028/concept-of-eigenvector-restricted-to-nonnegative-entries

Comment: it is easy to see that the maximum is obtained where $\|x\|=1$. Then, maybe you can use lagrangian multipliers for $x^Tx=1$ and see what happens?

Comment: maybe the wiki article for quadraticly constrained problems could be helpful as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program

Comment: @supinf with the lagrange multiplier approach I can't use the positivity constraint, though, right?

Comment: The objective is convex but I'm not minimizing, I'm maximizing and so standard convex solvers (or at least cvxpy) won't allow me to do it

Answer (score 1):

Given,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & x^T M \, x\\ \text{subject to} & \| x \| \leq 1\\ & x \geq 0\end{array}$$

We can rewrite the constraint $\|x||\le1$ to $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\le1$.

$$[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\begin{bmatrix}m_{11}&\cdots &m_{1n}\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\m_{n1}&\cdots&m_{nn}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n\end{bmatrix}$$

$$=x_1\sum_{i=1}^nx_im_{1i} + x_2\sum_{i=1}^nx_im_{2i}
 + \cdots+x_n\sum_{i=1}^nx_im_{ni}$$

Then, we will have the following model:

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
-\text{minimize} & -1(x_1\sum_{i=1}^nx_im_{1i} + x_2\sum_{i=1}^nx_im_{2i} + \cdots+x_n\sum_{i=1}^nx_im_{ni})\\\\
\text{subject to} & \sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\le1\\ & x \ge 0
\end{array}$$

Then, we can use the [Penalty function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_method) to solve this model via:

> **Initialization Step**: Let $\epsilon>0$ be a termination scalar. Choose an initial point $x_1$, a penalty parameter $\mu_1>0$, and a
> scalar $\beta>1$. Let $k=1$ and go to the Main Step.
>
> **Main Step**
>
> 1. Starting with $x_k$, solve the following problem: $$\min f(x)+\mu_k\alpha(x)$$
>    Let $x_{k+1}$ be an optimal solution and go to Step $2$.
> 2. If $\mu_k(x_{k+1})<\epsilon$, stop; otherwise $\mu_{k+1} = \beta\mu_k$, replace $k$ by $k+1$ and go to Step $1$.

where

$$\alpha(x)=[\max\{0, \sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2-1\}]^2$$

Traditionally, we usually let $\mu_1=10$ and $\beta = 2$. The inner function $\min f(x)+\mu_k\alpha(x)$ can be solved with the [Conjugate Gradient Method of Fletcher and Reeves](http://www.mymathlib.com/optimization/nonlinear/unconstrained/fletcher_reeves.html) via:

[image: 3]